# When I run the PDO script alone it work fine but when I put it in a function it will not work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I run the PDO script alone it runs just fine But when I run it in a function I get this error Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object. I can not figure out why it is happening.

```
$pid = 6;
$custid = 1;
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from signings WHERE pid = ? AND custid = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $custid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn(); 
echo $number_of_rows;




$pid = 6;
$custid = 1;

function test($custid,$pid){
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from signings WHERE pid = ? AND custid = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $custid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn(); 
echo $number_of_rows;

}

echo test($custid,$pid);
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `$db` is not visible inside your function. you need to add

```
function test($custid,$pid){
    global $db;
    [...]
}
```

inside your function or you should pass the db object to your function via parameter:

```
function test($db, $custid,$pid){
    [...]
}
```

another nice way ist to work with the factory patterns:

create a class db with a static method dbFactory and call it whenever you need to access your db

```
class db {
    public static function dbFactory($host, $dbase, $user, $pass) {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbase", $user, $pass);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);        
        return $pdo;
    }
}
$db = db::dbFactory('localhost','mydbname','myusername','mypassword');
```

Comment: It is better if all functions `return` something. So instead of `echo $number_of_rows;` use `return $number_of_rows;`